# How to export charts.js dynamic chart to PDF in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf, chart.js

I am trying to export charts.js doughnut chart to PDF, but the chart is broken when it is rendered. I am using wicked_pdf.

VIEW CODE ------------------------------------------------------------

```
.row
  = render 'analytics/reports/description' 


  / - CANVAS FOR DOUGHN UT CHART STARTS HERE
.row
  / - table row starts here
  .col-lg-12t
    %h2.telus-head2
      %span
        Green Standards Impact Report – 
        =@contact.name rescue nil

        - unless @projects.empty?
          = @projects.first.created_at.strftime("%b, %Y") rescue nil
          – 
          =@projects.last.created_at.strftime("%b, %Y") rescue nil

    .telus_border
      .roundgraph
        /%iframe#graph{frameborder: "0", height: "375", src: "/doughnut", width: "375"}
        #chart
          %canvas#canvas{height: "350", width: "350"}
          %canvas#canvas1{height: "225", width: "225"}
          .per
            = "#{number_to_percentage(@landfilled_diversion, precision: 0, format: "%n")}%"
          %p.percon
            Diverted
            %br
            from
            %br
            landfill

      .chart
        .green_bx
          .green_bx1
            .green_bx1a

              %h3=number_to_percentage(@landfilled_diversion, precision: 0, format: "%n") rescue nil

              %h4 %
              %p
                Diverted
                from
                landfill
            .ver_line
            .green_bx1b

              %h3=number_with_delimiter(Account.total_tonnage(@projects).round(0)) rescue nil
              %p Tons of surplus furniture diverted from landfill
          .green_bx2
            .green_bx2a
              %h3=number_to_percentage(Account.donated_percentage(@projects), precision: 0, format: "%n") rescue nil

              %h4 %
              %p Donated
            .ver_line2
            .green_bx2b

              %h3=number_to_currency(Account.total_donation_fmv(@projects), precision: 0) rescue nil
              %p of in-kind Charitable donations
          .green_bx3
            .green_bx3a
              %h3=number_to_percentage(Account.recycled_percentage(@projects), precision: 0, format: "%n") rescue nil

              %h4 %
              %p Recycled
          .green_bx4
            .green_bx4a

              %h3=number_to_percentage(Account.resold_percentage(@projects), precision: 0, format: "%n") rescue nil

              %h4 %
              %p Resold
          .green_bx5
            .green_bx5a

              %h3=number_to_percentage(Account.relocated_percentage(@projects), precision: 0, format: "%n") rescue nil

              %h4 %
              %p Relocated
          .green_bx6
            .green_bx6a

              %h3=number_to_percentage(Account.landfilled_percentage(@projects), precision: 0, format: "%n") rescue nil

              %h4 %
              %p Landfilled
          .share_link
            %a{href: "#"} Embeded in website
            %a{href: "#"} Copy URL
            %a{href: "#"} Share this case

  = hidden_field_tag "landfilled", @landfilled
  = hidden_field_tag "resold", @resold
  = hidden_field_tag "recycled", @recycled
  = hidden_field_tag "donated", @donated
  = hidden_field_tag "relocated", @relocated
  = hidden_field_tag "landfilled_diversion", @landfilled_diversion

  / - CANVAS FOR DOUGHN UT CHART ENDS HERE


= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "jquery"
= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "jquery_ujs"
= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed"
= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "jquery.mousewheel.min"
= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "Chart"
= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "doughnut_pdf"

= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrap'
= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'styles'
= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'report'
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE --------------------------------------------------------------

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var x = {
            //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
            segmentShowStroke : false,

            //String - The colour of each segment stroke
            segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",

            //Number - The width of each segment stroke
            segmentStrokeWidth : 1,

            //The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle.
            percentageInnerCutout : 50,

            //Boolean - Whether we should animate the chart 
            animation : false,

            //Number - Amount of animation steps
            animationSteps : 100,

            //String - Animation easing effect
            animationEasing : "easeOutBounce",

            //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
            animateRotate : false,

            //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
            animateScale : false,

            //Function - Will fire on animation completion.
            onAnimationComplete : null
        }

      var doughnutData = [

      {
      value : parseFloat(parseFloat($("#landfilled").val()).toFixed(2)),
      color : "#E9EAEC" 
      },
      {
      value: parseFloat(parseFloat($("#resold").val()).toFixed(2)),
      color:"#ffca30"
      },
      {
      value : parseFloat(parseFloat($("#recycled").val()).toFixed(2)),
      color : "#a0d06d"
      },
      {
      value : parseFloat(parseFloat($("#donated").val()).toFixed(2)),
      color : "#1ab6e6"
      },
      {
      value : parseFloat(parseFloat($("#relocated").val()).toFixed(2)),
      color : "#7293bc"
      }

      ];
      var doughnutData1 = [

      {
      value : parseFloat(parseFloat($("#landfilled").val()).toFixed(2)),
      color : "#E9EAEC"
      },
      {
      value : parseFloat(parseFloat($("#landfilled_diversion").val()).toFixed(2)),
      color : "#5db159"
      }



      ];

      var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData, x);
      var myDoughnut1 = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData1, x);

    });
```

HTML OUTPUT IMAGE FOR CHARTS.JS--------------------------
[image]

WHEN THE OUTPUT IMAGE FOR CHARTS.JS COMES ON WICKED PDF GENERATED PDF------------------
[image]

Comment: You have to provide more information if you want some help. How does your code look like?

Comment: You might consider reviewing this article: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @Momer - Hope this will helpful for you to give me a solution. Please help. I am using wicked_pdf which depends on wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this question, I managed to improve the quality of the exported chart on pdf with some tweaking. 
I'm using chartjs 2.0 but this should apply to older versions. wicked_pdf is 1.0.4

First I thought about getting the chart image from the canvas when it finished drawing and then put it on an image tag, but then realised it was a js timing problem, so I ended up fixing this just by letting rails wait more time for the page to render before generating the pdf.

In your controller when you do the render you can:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render  :pdf => 'report',
              :template => 'reports/report_test.html.erb',
              :layout => "report",
              :page_size => "A4",
              javascript_delay: 1000 # The relevant line is this one 
    end
  end
end
```